# simulate pressure border bottom css

Tags: html, css, border

```
.pressure{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
```

this css gives like this border bottom

[image]

what i want is like

[image]

is there any way to do it in css?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vz8qp4v/)

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588017/shape-resembling-a-compass-pointer-or-inner-part-of-a-safari-logo). It produces a similar needle shape. That one needs a rotateY and rotateZ, your shape would need a rotateX and rotateZ.

Comment: I have updated the other thread with a snippet for the shape resembling the one in this question also. I didn't want to post it here because it would look like I am almost duplicating answers.

Comment: so there is no way do design border bottom itself. we have to use separate div like `<div class='separator'></div>`? @Harry

Comment: No way that I am personally aware of. Maybe some complex stuff with `border-image` and/or gradients could help but that would have lower browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```css
.pressure{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%/60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pressure"</div>
```

Comment: this is curved up. how to make it straight as in picture?